# Select all tables and filter its data

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a search module that will show the data from different tables but I added a feature where I can search for specific data in the module.

all of these codes are working but my only problem here is how to implement the select all tables names.

```
    SET @sql = ' ;WITH [ROWS] AS
    (

        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY '+@colname+' '+@dir_sort+') AS [ROW],
        COUNT (accno) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) AS TOTAL_ROWS,
         accno, 
         accname, 
         add1, 
         zip, 
         dupload, 
         brdesc, 
         schcode
         FROM 'SELECT name from sys.tables where name like 'gen_048%'' <-- HERE IS MY PROBLEM

         where accno like ''%'+@accNum+'%'' or accname like ''%'+@accNum+'%'' or refdate + '''' + convert(varchar(10), refcount) like ''%'+@accNum+'%''

    )
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [ROWS]
WHERE
    [ROW] BETWEEN ('+cast(@page_num as varchar)+' - 1) * '+cast(@page_size as varchar)+' + 1 AND '+cast(@page_num as varchar)+' * '+cast(@page_size as varchar)+' '

exec( @sql)
```

Comment: Just use Full Text Search. No need to try and rebuild what is already there

Comment: but I need all the tables that is why I did this 'SELECT name from sys.tables where name like 'gen_048%' but that script shows all the table but it only reads on table name at a time.

Comment: That's the other problem - don't use string concatenation when you can use parameterized queries. It's not only that you'll get escaping wrong, you leave yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks

Comment: Write a static query (without dynamic SQL) for, say, three specific tables. Thus you'll realise how the final query would look like. Hint: most likely you'll use `UNION ALL`. After that start building the text of the query dynamically.

Comment: thanks sir @VladimirBaranov, I somehow get your point and I also consider using the UNION, I will send you a feedback once I did that, actually I am just having a dilemma in using union.